# Android Image Zooming why not use a scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview, android-imageview

I'm coming from iOS, where enable zooming is just placing a view in UIScrollView.

I see that in Android most of the solutions for zooming ImageViews are based on manipulating the ImageView coordinates based on touch events like in [ImageTouchView](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom) or [GestureImageView](https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview).

So I wonder why? What's the limitation of ScrollView in Android that doesn't allow zooming of ImageViews without customizing the ImageView itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScrollView only supports vertical scrolling (and HorizontalScrollView supports only horizontal scrolling). You can combine ScrollView and HorizontalScrollView and it works. But you can only scroll horizontal or vertical, at one time, and not diagonally. And this is only for scrolling, you still have to implement zooming.